# Как вставить OLE объект в Draw в LibreOffice?

Tags: python, uno

Есть таблица в Calc. Есть страница с данными в Draw. Все сделано с помощью pyuno. Как вставить таблицу из Calc в Draw программно через pyuno?

Если просто сделать copy/paste, то это не то, что нужно. Нужно выполнить такие действия:

> "Вставка" -> "Объект" -> "Объект OLE..." -> "Создать из файла" -> "Вводится имя файла документа Calc" -> "OK"

Как такое сделать через pyuno?

Пробовал через `com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper`, но не получилось. Выводит только окно с выбором типа объекта и дальше не идет.

У кого есть какие идеи?

Comment: Примеров использования не нашел, только https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/File:Uno-Arc.jpg

Answer (score 2):

**Короткий ответ:** не получится

**Длинный ответ:**

Команда *InsertObject* [не до конца реализована](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Getting_Started/Sometimes_the_macro_recorder_fails#How_the_macro_recorder_uses_the_dispatch_framework). Соответственно нужен другой путь.

Если вставить вручную объект в лист *Draw* и посмотреть на свойства вставленного объекта, то мы увидим объект [OLE2Shape](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/drawing/OLE2Shape.html),
у которого есть параметр `EmbeddedObject`, типа [XEmbeddedObject](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/embed/XEmbeddedObject.html).

Создать из файла `XEmbeddedObject`, пользуясь только API можно, воспользовавшись недокументированным сервисом

```
import uno
import unohelper

smgr = uno.getComponentContext().ServiceManager

# fname - имя файла
url = unohelper.systemPathToFileUrl(os.path.abspath(fname))
storageFactory = smgr.createInstance("com.sun.star.embed.StorageFactory")
storage = storageFactory.createInstance()
medium = (PropertyValue("URL", 0, url, 0), )
objDescr = (PropertyValue(), )

eoc = smgr.createInstance("com.sun.star.embed.EmbeddedObjectCreator")
# недокументированный сервис, реализующий интерфейс com.sun.star.embed.XEmbedObjectCreator

eo = eoc.createInstanceInitFromMediaDescriptor(storage, "TestObject", medium, objDescr)
xeoType = uno.getTypeByName("com.sun.star.embed.XEmbeddedObject")
xeo = eo.queryInterface(xeoType)
# xeo уже содержит заргуженный объект. Если файл является файлом OpenOffice 
# можно получить доступ к документу через xeo.getComponent()
```

Создать `OLE2Shape` и добавить на лист можно как описано на примере [вставки диаграммы](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Charts/Creating_a_Chart_OLE_Object_in_Draw_and_Impress)

```
doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
oleShape = doc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.OLE2Shape")
# создаем пустой объект
doc.getDrawPages().getByIndex(0).add(oleShape)
# добавляем объект на лист
# oleShape.setSize(xeo.getVisualAreaSize(1))
# задаем размеры по загруженному XEmbeddedObject
# oleShape.setPosition(Point(1000, 1000))
# задаем положение объекта на листе
```

А вот теперь проблема. Нужно скрестить ужа и ежа, то есть вставить `xeo` в `oleShape`, но у параметра `EmbeddedObject` есть только геттер, то есть этот параметр реализован в режиме "только чтение". Создать объект можно задавая параметр `CLSID`. Например для книги *Calc'а*

```
oleShape.CLSID = "47BBB4CB-CE4C-4E80-a591-42d9ae74950f"
```

Однако для привязки существующего `XEmbeddedObject` к `OLE2Shape` доступных путей в API нету.

Идея для реализации задачи, описанной в вопросе пока только одна: загружать книгу *Calc* в `XEmbeddedObject`, создавать `OLE2Shape` с пустой книгой и копировать нужный диапазон ячеек из `XEmbeddedObject` в `OLE2Shape.EmbeddedObject`. По сути - костыль, но других вариантов не найдено.